# Titanium get moved pin coords

Tags: javascript, maps, titanium, coordinates, appcelerator

I am trying to get the coords after i moved the pin in the map. I used the user current location and when i open the map shows correctly. But when i move the pin to another street, won't able to get the new coords still showing the same coords.

Here is my code

```
var Map = require('ti.map');

if(Ti.Geolocation.locationServicesEnabled){

Ti.Geolocation.addEventListener('location', function(e) {

    if (e.error){

        alert('Error: ' + e.error);

    }else {
        longitude = e.coords.longitude;
        latitude = e.coords.latitude;



var mapView = Map.createView({
top          : 0,
left         : 0,
bottom       : 0,
right        : 0,
mapType      : Map.STANDARD_TYPE,
animate      : true,
regionFit    : true,
userLocation : false,
touchEnabled : true,
draggable    : true
});



view3.add(mapView);
view3.add(boton2);

var annotation = Map.createAnnotation({
latitude    : latitude,
longitude   : longitude,
title       : 'Selecciona Tu Ubicación',
draggable   : true
});

mapView.setAnnotations([annotation]);

var region = {
latitude       : latitude,
longitude      : longitude,
animate        : true,
latitudeDelta  : 0.005,
longitudeDelta : 0.005
};
mapView.setRegion(region);

mapView.addEventListener('pinchangedragstate', function(e) {
    Ti.API.info(longitude + ' - ' + latitude);
}); 
    }

});

}else{

alert('Por favor habilita los servicios de ubicación');
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're logging the variables you've set manually, that won't change automatically. You'll have to use the annotation to check the coordinates.

If you look at the [documentation](https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Modules.Map.View-event-pinchangedragstate) for the event you'll see the annotation is also returned there.

```
mapView.addEventListener('pinchangedragstate', function(e) {
    Ti.API.info(e.annotation.longitude + ' - ' + e.annotation.latitude);
});
```

Comment: ohh, I got it now. Thank you Rene!